# watch firebase list on server-side

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to write a program to watch a list of data objects in firebase (for workflow status changes). This program will run 24/7.

It seems like all the supported libraries so far (javacript or fireSharp) are all running on client side.   I can write a web page and put it there to run 24/7, but I am afraid the session will either timeout or stopped at some point (or authentication session expired).  I don't want to eat up lots of firebase bandwidth either.

I don't know if I am using the right solution (if I use a web page to monitor the data status).  I thought I can write a "server side" service to watch a firebase list changes.

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: The Admin SDK that Cartant points at was indeed made for this use-case. It used to be called the "Server SDK", but that also was confusing. :-/ Also have a look at [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) for managing such workflow-based tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise!  reading it now..